# C# Collect Sum of Rows

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Get_Total]
    @ID int
as
    select Total 
    from Order_details 
    where Id_order = @ID
```

If there are more than one row, I want to get the sum of the rows, so I tried to do that with a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < set.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
{                                                
     Total.Text += Convert.ToInt32(set.Tables[1].Rows[i][0]).ToString();
}
```

but it doesn't work, it returns a big sum so the loop didn't stop.

Help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, you are doing `string`  concatenation here, which might gives you big concatenated number rather `Sum`.

You could do this.

```
int value= 0;
for (int i = 0; i < set.Tables[1].Rows.Count; i++)
{                                                
  value += Convert.ToInt32(set.Tables[1].Rows[i][0]);
}

Total.Text = value.ToString();
```

Another simple approach, using `Linq`.

```
Total.Text = set.Tables[1].AsEnumberable()
                          .Select(row=>int.Parse(row[0]))
                          .Sum()
                          .ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

why not sum at the database:

```
select Sum(Total) from Order_details 
where Id_order = @ID
```

Although that suggests there is something wrong with your schema design....

Answer (score 1):

Do the sum in SQL:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Get_Total] (
    @ID int
)
as
begin
    select sum(Total) as Total
    from Order_details 
    where Id_order = @ID;
end;
```

I don't know why you would do this as a stored procedure.  You can readily do this as a user-defined function instead -- then it is easier to get the results.